# how to get the color in rgb to put it in the MySQL database JColorChooser

Tags: java, jcolorchooser

How can I get the color of the JColorChooser in rgb so I can save it to MySQL and use it to my Label when I want to use it?

My current doesnt give the specific number instead it gives me the output of

```
java.awt.Color[r=102,g=204,b=0]
```

Is there a way of getting just the rga number?

```
class GetColorChooser implements ChangeListener{

public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    String lol = jccChooser.getColor().toString();
    System.out.print(lol);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Color#getRGB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB%28%29)

```
int rgbColor = jccChooser.getColor().getRGB();
```

Comment: Sorry I can thumbs up I dont have 15 repu